# Запустить Java код в Python

Tags: java, python, qgis

Можно ли запустить код, который написан на Java, из программы, которая написана на Python? Как, например, asm в c++.
А точнее, как из плагина на Питоне для Qgis вызвать код, написанный на Java.

Comment: Средствами только питона - нет, нельзя. Для исполнения Java нужна Java-машина, которой в Питоне нет

Comment: Если используете Jython, то по идее вы сможете использовать Java классы. Но просто так встраивать код на Java в код на Python не получится.

Comment: Получится. Проект https://pybee.org позволяет, в том числе, компилировать классы Java в код Python. Ну, а в Kivy (фреймворк для разработки приложений на Python под Android, Windows, Linux...) код Java запускается из коробки, зачем вы человека вводите в заблуждение, если сами не в курсе!?

Comment: @Xyanight у меня вот стоит Питон, не самый свежий но все же: Python 2.7.13 и Python 3.6.1. Расскажите как мне из этого чистого Питона запустить Hello World на Java.

Comment: Ну, вы бы для начала почитали о PyBee... О PyJnius в Kivy. Информации море.

Comment: @Xyanight, как мой комментарий противоречит тому что вы сказали? Всегда можно найти какой-то внешний инструмент.

Comment: Я не знаю в каких отношениях java и python, просто предположил. Есть замечательная система Qgis по работе с картографическими данными, в которой можно создать свой плагин на python. Имеется алгоритм обработки точек на карте, который написан на java. Хотелось бы использовать готовый алгоритм на java в этом плагине, а не переписывать его на python.

Comment: Внешние команды из плагина можно вызывать? (`subprocess.run(cmd)`) Вы это в самом вопросе укажите: *"как из плагина на Питоне для Qgist вызвать код, написанный на Java"* Нажмите [edit]

Comment: Ещё есть инструмент JPyPe - https://github.com/jpype-project/jpype